# name splitting in base r

Tags: r, regex

I've got a list of names that have been written in a messy way in a single column. I'm trying to extract first name, middle names and last names out of this column to store separately.

To do this, I gsub the first word from each name entry and save it as the first name. I then remove the last word and first word of each entry and save that as the middle names. Then i gsub the last word from each entry and save it as the last name.

This gave me a problem, because for entries that have only one name entered (so 'kevin' instead of 'kevin banks') my code saves the first name as the last name ('kevin kevin'). I tried to fix it using a for-loop that deletes the lastname column if the original name entry has only 1 word. When i try this, ALL the lastname entries are empty, even the ones that do have a last name!

This is my code:

```
df <- data.frame(ego = c("linda", "wendy pralice of rivera", "bruce springsteen", "dan", "sam"))

df$firstname <- gsub("([A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", df$ego)
df$middlename <- gsub("^\\w*\\s*", "", gsub("\\s*\\w*\\.*$", "", df$ego))
df$lastname <- gsub("^.* ([A-Za-z]+)", "\\1", df$ego)
for(n in df$ego) {
  if(lengths(strsplit(n, " ")) == 1) {
    df$lastname <- ""
  }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are 4 fields put double quotes around the middle two. For example, `a b c d` would be changed to `a "b c" d` giving `s1`.  (If there are not 4 fields then no substitution is done and `s1` is set to `df$ego`.)

If there are exactly two fields insert double quotes between the two.  For example, `a b` would be changed to `a "" b`. (If there are not exactly two fields then no substitution is done and `s2` is set to `s1`).

Finally read in.

```
s1 <- sub('^(\\w+) (\\w+ \\w+) (\\w)+$', '\\1 "\\2" \\3', df$ego)
s2 <- sub('^(\\w+) (\\w+)$', '\\1 "" \\2', s1)
read.table(text = s2, as.is = TRUE, fill = TRUE, 
  col.names = c("first", "middle", "last"))
```

giving:

```
  first     middle        last
1 linda                       
2 wendy pralice of           a
3 bruce            springsteen
4   dan                       
5   sam
```

Comment: Hey, in my dataset an error occured. There are some people with multiple middle names (see my updated question). Your example doesn't work for those cases, it saves the last name (4th word in string) as a new row's first name. could you explain what you did? maybe i can figure out a workaround.